# Change font in all sideways tables

Tags: tables, fonts, formatting, changes

Is there any way how to change the font in all sideways tables of the document? The following code

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{sidewaystable}
     {\renewcommand\familydefault{mdput}
      \@float{table}}
     {\end@float}
\makeatother
```

changes the font but a rotation of the table is ignored. Unfortunately,

```
 \@float{sidewaystable}}
```

does not work.  Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use etoolbox to insert commands at the begin of the document. It will not work for arbitrary font commands, as floats resets the fonts at the begin, but a change of familydefault will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{sidewaystable}{\renewcommand\familydefault{mdput}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{sidewaystable}
\lipsum[1]
\end{sidewaystable}


\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Vielen Dank :-)...